# How can I determine the collector voltage of Q1 in this circuit?

Tags: transistors

How can I determine the collector voltage of Q1 in this circuit?

I suppose it is very simple but it really puzzled me.

Thanks all.

[image]

Comment: Smells a bit too much like homework, which would be OK if you show what you tried to solve it. Hint: there's a capacitor, what does it prevent? Also: the question is actually incomplete, it should say if the capacitor is charged or not and if you're allowing it the time to charge or not.

Comment: Yes, it's very simple. Have a go and we might help.

Comment: The REAL world answer is, NEITHER.

Answer (score 1):

The real world answer to..

*"What is the collector voltage with respect to ground, is it zero, or 15V?"*

is **NEITHER!**

The model below is what you really have for DC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn45Ia.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Real world components and the PCB, wiring etc. have intrinsic and parasitic resistances and capacitances. As such, in reality, your model looks more complicated.

As you can see, there is a resistor divider in there between the leakage resistance of the capacitor and the leakage resistance of the transistor (Which includes the parasitic resistance of the build). There is also a capacitor divider between the capacitor itself and the junction capacitances of the transistor and wiring, C_OFF.

As such the final voltage will be set by that resistor divider.

When you first power the circuit the collector voltage will be dictated by the capacitor divider then decay to the resistor divider voltage. How long it takes to reach that voltage will be dictated by the sizes of those resistances and capacitances.

Note, there are also numerous inductances not shown in the above model that complicate matters even more.

Interestingly it is actually very hard to measure this. Since the values involved are usually very large resistances and very small capacitances, attaching pretty much any measuring equipment disturbs the balance significantly.

Comment: That's true...but I think what you describe is far beyond what the circuit was trying to show to a reader. Even if you type 'neither' in big capitals :-)

Comment: @TonyM yes I know :). But as a homework question it is dull and uninteresting and I would not even bother answering. However, as a real world answer, it is much more entertaining.

Comment: Oh spot on...looks like we're both having a dull day in the office and there's nothing interesting out the window :-D

Answer (score 0):

With the base at the emitter voltage, the transistor will be off.

In theory, that means that the collector has infinite impedance to ground and that the C1 lower plate is floating. Therefore, C1 never charges and has 0 V across its plates. So the lower plate is at the same potential as the upper plate: 15 V.

In practice, there will be a leakage current, however tiny, through the collector and C1 will charge, however slowly. So over a long time, C1 will charge to 15 V and the lower plate will be at 0 V. I doubt if that's the answer being looked for, though.

Comment: Actually, if we want to go there, the collector will end up at the resistor divider voltage set up by the leakage resistances of both the capacitor and the transistor and you would also have to factor in the capacitances of the transistor junctions. Ultimately it will end up somewhere in between 15V and 0V.

Comment: Good @Trevor, as per the last line of my answer, it's not really what a circuit like that's trying to illustrate, so I just wouldn't go there :-)

Comment: "Therefore, C1 never charges and has 0 V across its plates." No, that simply means that whatever voltage is impressed on the cap, it will not subsequently change. Since the initial state of the cap is not specified (although the homework probably assumes 0 volts), it can be anything. Within the range 15 to 15 minus the breakdown Vce of the transistor.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, "that simply means that whatever voltage is impressed on the cap, it will not subsequently change". No. In the theory case being discussed, the circuit is closed. No path is shown to charge the capacitor. Therefore there is not one. That's the theory case.